# Want to retrieve a column from a table A where that column is in table B and row less than 2

Tags: phpmyadmin

If a donor wants to donate, he should be linked to the receiver in `receive donation table`, who have not received the donation or received donation less than 2 times?

[image: The image is here]

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN for this. Something like this:

```
SELECT A.column1 FROM table_A A
INNER JOIN 
table_B B ON A.column1 = B.column2 
group by B.column2 
having COUNT(B.column2)<2
```

Comment: Thanks very much sir